# Creation of a "username" using javascript Quantifiers?

Tags: javascript, quantifiers

I'm just beginning to learn Javascript.

Now to my question. I think it has to do with quantifiers, but I'm not sure. I have to write a regular expression that will match a single "username" with the following attributes:

- Must contain at least 5 characters, but no more than 30.
- Must contain only characters that are: alphabetic (upper and lowercase), numeric, hyphens, and underscore.
- Must start with an alphabetic character.

Comment: "Java" and "JavaScript" are two completely different languages.

Comment: You forgot to ask your question.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, and good luck with that, age is not a problem if you want to learn. You can test and figure out regular expressions at [regex101](https://regex101.com/), start with something like `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{5,30}` etc.

Comment: Your question title says "creation", but your question text says "match". Which is it?

Comment: "regular expression" is sort of a blanket term. there are different implementations and it may differ slightly depending on which platform is used, so you should clarify whether you're working with java or javascript which are two entirely separate languages which are not compatibe with one another. also, as a general rule on stack overflow, you should post the code you're having trouble with. Post the pattern you've worked out so far and someone will help. on SO, the way you ask the question is almost as important as the question  itself.

Comment: since you mentioned javascript twice and java only once i'm going to assume you mean javascript and edit the question to reflect that..

Comment: Thanks to everyone's helpful tips. I promise to improve, taking special note to how to phrase my questions. To clarify, I'm taking a basic Java course and the instructor asked me to just plug in my solution into the regex101 regular expressions tester @adeneo mentioned. Here's my first attempt which received no matches. \A(?=\w{5,29}\z)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,})(?=\D*\d).* (I used test options such as ASDF1. 12345, Asd1#. ASD%5.). Thanks again for the warm welcoming. I'll strive to become a contributing member.

Comment: Something like this maybe -> https://jsfiddle.net/1b1Lwn1j/

Comment: How can I change this, so it always begins with an alphabetic character and written in regular expression that I can change into java verses javascript? By the way thanks for sending me the earlier reply. I'm using the regular expression tester in Regex, you recommended and that works great. @adeneo

Comment: The example I posted has to start with `a-zA-Z` to be valid, so it already begins with an alphabetic character? I'm not too familiar with the differences between Java and Javascript when it comes to regex, but I assume both uses some substandard of Perl regex'es, so it should be pretty much the same ?

Comment: Here's an inline link to [Regex] http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html. If you have time I submitted your suggestion which got match's on everything, but the test option "12345" should have failed because it didn't start with an alpha character, which is my 3rd requirement. I thought adding \A would guarantee that the alpha "A" would have to be the first character. I understand if you don't have time to respond. I do thank you for your help.